# Outlook connected to Office365 synchronizing Inbox after setting MAPI properties on messages

Tags: c++, outlook, office365, mapi

I have Outlook 2013/2016 connected to Office365. I have a program that once in a while scans my Inbox and sets MAPI properties on the scanned emails (using `HrSetOneProp` followed by `SaveChanges(KEEP_OPEN_READWRITE)`. after such a scan Outlook is stuck for a very long time on "Updating Inbox" and doesn't receive any emails during this time. It seems that Outlook detects the MAPI property changes and tries to synchronize the messages in the Inbox back to the Office365 cloud.

Is there a way to set properties on messages without making Outlook synchronizing the messages to the cloud? (btw, the PR_LAST_MODIFICATION_TIME property doesn't change after I set my properties on a message)

Answer (score 0):

No, if it was possible to set a property on a message and avoid synchronizing it, that would be a bug, don't you agree?

Sounds like you want to store extra properties in some other place other than the message itself. Using an associated (hidden) message to store your dictionary of `<`entry id vs your custom prop`>` would probably work a lot better.

Comment: yes, I do agree. however, the fact that Outlook doesn't "multitask" and doesn't receive emails while synchronizing changes to the cloud is quite disturbing... thanks for the suggestion - I'll go this way.